# Under what circumstances is a fully connected layer similar to PCA?

Tags: architecture, facial-recognition, principal-component-analysis, content-based-image-retrieval

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06626.pdf) on image retrieval where the goal is to train a network that produces highly discriminative descriptors (aka embeddings) for input images. If you are familiar with facial recognition architectures, it is similar in that the network is trained with matching / non-matching pairs and triplet loss.

The paper discusses the use of PCA and whitening on the training set of descriptors as a means of further improving the discriminability (second to last block in image below, fig 1a of paper). This all make sense to me.

[image]

**Where I'm confused** is where they replace PCA/whitening with a trainable fully connected layer with bias. I do understand that PCA+whitening is just the composition of of two linear transformations (ie rotation + (un)squishing in each dimension) and that these are the same as having one linear transformation but:

- How is PCA+whitening equivalent to a learnable fully connected layer? Is there some theorem or paper explaining that training a fully connected layer with triplet loss is somehow statistically equivalent to PCA and whitening?
- Why is there a bias?